# Matching two column values

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. 'user_cities' and 'visits'. I want to check if a user visited a city which he was not supposed to visit.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_cities` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT,
    `name` varchar(255),
    `city_id` INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `visits` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT,
    `visit_id` INT,
    `city_id` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `user_cities` VALUES
(1, 1, 'John', 35),
(2, 1, 'John', 36),
(3, 1, 'John', 37),
(4, 2, 'Michael', 38),
(5, 2, 'Michael', 39);

INSERT INTO `visits` VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 35),
(2, 1, 2, 36),
(3, 1, 3, 38),
(4, 2, 4, 38),
(5, 2, 5, 39);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68c658

Example: John must visit only 35, 36 and 37. Michael must visit 38 and 39. These are defined in 'user_cities'

However, John has visited 38 (visits id 3)

How can i query users that visited the wrong city?

Comment: Also, separate out users and cities.

Comment: I am not clear on the requirement when you say ' John must visit only 35, 36 and 37;' does that mean its ok if john has visited any of these (possibly all 3) and not ok if he has visited any other? and does 'Michael must visit 38 and 39' mean that if michael HAS visited both then it's ok but if he HAS NOT visited both its not ok? And it's not ok if michael has visited any city other than 38,39?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not familiar with SQL this kind of problem is a bit trickier than it appears.

You want to select the information from the visits where that visit is not specified by user_cities.  The usual way to do this is to use a LEFT JOIN to the user_cities table for the record that validates the visit, and then to find entries where the LEFT JOIN can't find a match.

So your query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM visits
LEFT JOIN user_cities
    ON(visits.user_id = user_cities.user_id AND
       visits.city_id = user_cities.city_id)
WHERE user_cities.id IS NULL
```

Of course you would probably also extend the query to give you the name of the user (and the coty, but that's not in your example code)

Comment: And avoid evil `SELECT *`

Comment: Perfect. This code works for me. It found the fault visits

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72d675/3

Comment: This only flags users who visited blacklisted cities.  It does not also ensure that a given user visited all whitelisted cities.

Comment: @Tim Bielgeleisen - true, but the OP's question was "How can i query users that visited the wrong city?"  To find user who have not visited everything use the same logic but start with the user_cities table, LEFT JOIN to to the visits table and find all entries without a vist.

Comment: Fair enough, but I interpreted `John must visit only 35, 36 and 37` as part of the requirement.  Anyway, downvote removed +1.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this is via a full outer join (which MySQL doesn't even support, so we have to use a workaround):

```
SELECT COALESCE(user_id_1, user_id_2) AS user_id_matching
FROM
(
    SELECT
        uc.user_id AS user_id_1,
        uc.city_id AS city_id_1,
        v.user_id AS user_id_2,
        v.city_id AS city_id_2
    FROM user_cities uc
    LEFT JOIN visits v
        ON uc.user_id = v.user_id AND uc.city_id = v.city_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        uc.user_id AS user_id_1,
        uc.city_id AS city_id_1,
        v.user_id AS user_id_2,
        v.city_id AS city_id_2
    FROM user_cities uc
    RIGHT JOIN visits v
        ON uc.user_id = v.user_id AND uc.city_id = v.city_id
    WHERE uc.user_id IS NULL
) t
GROUP BY COALESCE(user_id_1, user_id_2)
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN user_id_1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
    COUNT(CASE WHEN user_id_2 IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

### Demo

Comment: thank you for the answer Tim, however i need to query for the city id's aswell. I can not hard code it as (35, 36 and 37). I need to check if a user have the permission to visit that city by matching user_id in both user_cities and visits

Answer (score 0):

You can try using left join

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68c658/7)**

```
select a.user_id,a.city_id
FROM visits a left join user_cities b on a.user_id=b.user_id and 
a.city_id=b.city_id
where b.user_id is null
```

OUTPUT:

```
1   John    37
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the effort. I added a new demo
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2b5faa/1

John visited 39 too, but your code still showing only 37